# How to implement angular grid system using *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, angular5, ngfor

How to achieve the below mentioned result in Angular5  using ngFor

Assume I have an array defined in Angular5 component. How to display the array as given below.

```
<div class='row'>
 <div class='col-3'>1</div>
<div class='col-3'>2</div>
<div class='col-3'>3</div>
<div class='col-3'>4</div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
 <div class='col-3'>5</div>
<div class='col-3'>6</div>
<div class='col-3'>7</div>
<div class='col-3'>8</div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
 <div class='col-3'>9</div>
<div class='col-3'>10</div>
<div class='col-3'>11</div>
<div class='col-3'>12</div>
</div>
```

I want to use angular5 ngFor. Assume values are getting from rest api. Sorry for the grammar.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: where is the rest api response???

Comment: <ng-container *ngFor="Array"><div class='row'>
 <div class='col-3'>{{i}}</div>
<div class='col-3'>{{i}}</div>
<div class='col-3'>{{i}}</div>
<div class='col-3'>{{i}}</div>
</div></ng-container>

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-container let obj of objs><div class='row'>
 <div class='col-3'>{{obj.i}}</div>
<div class='col-3'>{{obj.i}}</div>
<div class='col-3'>{{obj.i}}</div>
<div class='col-3'>{{obj.i}}</div>
</div></ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your array structure?

for example

```
let rows=[
  {ROW_ID:1, COLUMS:[{COLUMN_ID:"ROW1_COL1"}, {COLUMN_ID:"ROW1_COL2"}, {COLUMN_ID:"ROW1_COL3"}]}
  {ROW_ID:2, COLUMS:[{COLUMN_ID:"ROW2_COL1"}, {COLUMN_ID:"ROW2_COL2"}, {COLUMN_ID:"ROW2_COL3"}]}
  {ROW_ID:3, COLUMS:[{COLUMN_ID:"ROW3_COL1"}, {COLUMN_ID:"ROW3_COL2"}, {COLUMN_ID:"ROW3_COL3"}]}
]    

<div *ngFor="let row of rows">
  {{row.ID_ROW}}
  <div class='row' *ngFor="let colum of row.COLUMS">
    {{colum.COLUMN_ID}}
  </div>
 </div>
```

This will get you this image from result:

[image]